# Database accessible by multiple devices

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm quiet new to databases and SQLlite in general so I'm sure there's probably an easier way to do this but...

1) How can I store a database online so it is accessable by multiple devices? If this isn't clear, an example of what I'm trying to do can be seen on the Android app "whatsapp". When you update your status(i.e. set it as available or busy), it show's on everyone's device.

2) if this is too complicated to explain on here, can you recommend a tutorial series?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can store your data on your online database but first learn about webservices and how it works. As for tutorial I think this one can give you an idea on how it will work:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Also take note that SQLite database are stored locally on your device. :)